# Web security authentication issue in Yii2

Tags: php, security, session, authentication, yii2

I have a website online and recently someone reported me a serius bug

The User was logged and sent a link (without any credential in url) to a friend.
The second user strangely had access and seemed logged as the first one account!! (The second user visited the website for first time)

The same issue happened before 20 days to another user (with other user)

I use the latest version of Yii2 and my configuration was

```
'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => 'my-csrf-user',
            'cookieValidationKey' => <random string>,
            'enableCookieValidation' => true,
            'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'path\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => 'identity-user', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'session-user',
        ],
```

I tried to reproduce this bug (using chrome and firefox at the same PC) by myself without luck (no found any problem)

Do you have any idea what is going on ?
Is there any stateless issue in my configuration? I suspect the enableAutoLogin but I am not sure.

I use cache only from specific queries
I use CDN and https protocol.

Do you thing that the problem maybe on server configuration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the CDN caching those pages perhaps…?

Comment: I requested to hosting provider. I dont use CDN but ONLY nginx cache. "The Nginx caches both dynamic and static resources and has few bypass rules for the most common CMS applications' login pages, so that such issues could not occur. " He suggested me to disable NGINX or Write some rules to disable NGINX cache on login/signup " What you suggest to me ?

Comment: It might be related to the controller and action this link points to. Please share the code.

Comment: What does shared link look like? Please also show the Controller handling this a link - to see access control, and the action code.

Comment: Its a simple link that even a guest-user can have access (and should be). Link has not any session or cookies or user id on url, this error not happen every time so I cannot reproduce it. I had a discussion with a techincal of server hosting-provider, and told me that may is cache of nignx... We have disabled the nginx cache and we waiting if this bug will happen again.

Comment: Bizley I didn't modify/override the Yii2 login of Authentication